# I need to re-update the old text file from new text file JAVA

Tags: java, netbeans

My program ask for user to enter a 13 digit number and searches it from file name ("Voter Database.txt"). Now if I edit some record and I need to write it on another file named ("Voter Database Copy.txt").

In the same program, the search function originally (must) search from file name ("Voters Database.txt") but if I update the and copy the record to a new file, I am left with searching from the wrong and not updated file.

This is the edit code.

```
Scanner in=new Scanner (System.in);
    String cnic,vn,list,nm,age,adrs;
    try{
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Voters Database.txt"));
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Voters Database Copy.txt"));
        String s;    String s1; String s2;
        System.out.println("Enter CNIC to edit the record");
        s1=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter New CNIC,if applicable");
        cnic=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter New Vote No,if applicable");
        vn=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter New List No,if applicable");
        list=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter New Name,if applicable");
        nm=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter New Age,if applicable");
        age=in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter New address,if applicable");
        adrs=in.nextLine();
        s2="CNIC: "+cnic+" Vote Number: "+vn+" List No: "+list+" Name: "+nm+" Age: "+age+" Address: "+adrs;
        s=br.readLine();
        while(s!=null){
          if(s.contains(s1))
          {
              bw.write(s2);
              bw.newLine();
          }
          else
          {
              bw.write(s);
              bw.newLine();
          }
          s=br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
        bw.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.err.println("IO EXCEPTION");
    }
```

Comment: Help how? where? with what code? in what way? Please first help us by improving this question, including showing relevant code and providing more relevant context. Please check out the [tour], [help] and [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections.

Comment: public static void search(){
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        String cnic;
        System.out.println("Enter CNIC");
        cnic=in.nextLine();
        try{
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Voters Database.txt"));
            String s=br.readLine();
            while(s!=null){
                int index=s.indexOf("CNIC");
                String m=s.substring(index+6);
                float x=Float.parseFloat(m);
                if (x==cnic){
                    System.out.println(s);
                }
               br.readLine();
            }

Comment: Sorry about that. New on the website and pretty tense.

Comment: Code loses its formatting when posted in comments, as you can see, so please avoid doing this. Instead [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34464191/edit) and post the code there. Also improve your question's text to provide a full explanation of your problem, and finally, please do read the links that I've provided above as they will tell you how to improve your questions on this site. Luck.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels done. Please see the code

Comment: Thanks for the update to your question, and I know that this will frustrate you, but it would help if you showed some more, including the format of the text file -- just how is the data layed out in this file? Some suggestions right off the bat -- get user interaction out of the search method. Instead, pass in a String cnic parameter, so that other code that has user interaction can query information from the user, get the desired cnic String and pass it into this method. Next, don't output the results in `System.out.println(...)` fashion, but rather ...

Comment: ...return the result to the calling code either as a String or as a new object. A big bug -- you're calling `br.readLine()` and discarding/ignoring the result returned. Google how to use a BufferedReader to iterate through a text file as this has been shown in many other questions on this site. You'll want to keep cnic a String and compare Strings with Strings. You probably want to use the String `contains(...)` method in there.

Comment: Clarification: by "get user interaction out", I meant remove all uses of System.in and System.out.println (except for temporary debugging purposes) within this method.

Comment: Please see edits to answer. If any questions, please ask.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comments,

- get user interaction out of the search method, in other words, avoid using System.in and System.out (except for temporary use for debuggin).
- Instead, pass in a String cnic parameter, so that other code that has user interaction can query information from the user, get the desired cnic String and pass it into this method.
- don't output the results in System.out.println(...) fashion, but rather return the result to the calling code either as a String or as a new object.
- A big bug -- you're calling `br.readLine()` and discarding/ignoring the result returned, i.e., you're not assigning the String returned into a String: `line = br.readLine();` except once before the loop.
- I would read in the line within the while loop condition: `String line = ""` and then `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {`
- You probably want to use the String contains(...) method in there.

Pseudo-code to explain the steps. There really is no need at this stage to use index of, since all you need to do is call `contains(...)` on each line of String read in from the BufferedReader. You will need to use `indexOf(...)` when parsing the line of interest to extract the data it contains however.

```
public search method, takes a cnic String parameter, returns a String
    declare result String, set = to ""
    open file within a try block, create BufferedReader
        declare String variable line, assign "" to it
        while loop, in condition, read from buffered reader into line, and loop while not null
            Check if line contains cnic String. No need for index of here, just contains
                if so, assign line to result String.
        end while loop
    end open file, create BufferedReader
    close BufferedReader (or use try with resources)
    return result String

end of method
```

---

When you want to parse the line of interest, you will need to get several ints:

- the index of plus the length of the `"CNIC: "` String
- the index of the `" Voter Number: "` String
- plus its length
- And the length of the String.

Using these numbers, experiment with extracting your data... you'll get it.